# Is Rgraphviz no longer available for R?

Tags: r

I am running R version 3.0.1 in a 64 bit OS, and I have tried to install `Rgraphviz` 3 different ways:

1) I have used `install.packages(Rgraphviz)`, but I get the error

`Error in install.packages(Rgraphviz) : object 'Rgraphviz' not found`

2) I have tried going through `Packages` > `Install Packages` in the R window, but I cannot find Rgraphviz

3) When I go through CRAN, at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rgraphviz/index.html, I get the message "Package ‘Rgraphviz’ was removed from the CRAN repository."

Does anyone know if there is any way I can get Rgraphviz, or if there is a suitable alternate?

Answer (score 87):

You need to install it directly from the [bioconductors](http://www.bioconductor.org/) site.

For R versions >= 3.5:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Rgraphviz")
```

For older R versions:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Rgraphviz")
```

More info can be found [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/install/).

Comment: I tried that, but when I tried using `graphviz.plot(x)` I got an error that it could not find the function

Comment: The `graphviz.plot()` function is not in the Rgraphviz package, it is in the bnlearn package and depends on the Rgraphviz package. So you also need to load the bnlearn package: `library(bnlearn)`

Comment: Do you have the bnlearn package installed? `install.packages("bnlearn")`

Comment: I am getting error `Error in plot(agread(ff)) : could not find function "agread"` while executing `plot(agread(ff))`. Is there any solution?

Comment: In my case it work, but the labels are so tiny that I cannot see the words inside them. What could I do?

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you

Answer (score -5):

You just need to remember that the instruction `install.packages` requires you to enclose the package name between quotes, like this:

```
install.packages("Rgraphviz")
```

Comment: Though true that quotes are required, since Rgraphviz was removed from the CRAN repo this will not work. Must source it differently as outlined by answer above.