# Generating a random directed acyclic graph in R is showing loops and bidirections

Tags: r, graph

I'm using R to generate a DAG (Directed Acyclic graph). 
With the following code I generate an Erdős–Rényi graph.

```
library(igraph)
aph <- erdos.renyi.game(12, 0.1, type=c("gnp", "gnm"),
                          directed = TRUE, loops = FALSE)
```

The problem is that even it says that

```
directed = TRUE ,`loops = FALSE`
```

the code is still generating loops and the graphs are not directed. 
In image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGfT7.png) the vertex `2` and `11` contains an bidirectional edge. 
Also in image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XARL.png) there is a loop from nodes `6`, `9` and `7`.

[image: First graph]

[image: Second graph]

How can I solve this problem and generate a correct DAG?

Comment: Hi! The graph is directed, it can just have an edge that goes from A to B and another one that goes fromB to A. I'll look up about the loops :) What's your desired result? A DAG right?

Comment: Well a directed graph with orientation, i.e., If there is a path from A to B then it should not be a path from B to A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a random DAG you can use the pcalg library

```
library(pcalg)
set.seed(101)
myDAG <- randomDAG(n = 20, prob= 0.2, lB = 0.1, uB = 1)
plot(myDAG)
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and in this environment there are some errors when installing the pcalg package. There are missing packages that are not available in CRAN. Therefore, they have to be installed in this way. Please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434335/how-to-plot-a-complete-graph-in-r/25434810) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023300/is-rgraphviz-no-longer-available-for-r).